# Tensorflow object detection:ValueError: cannot reshape array

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have trained "SSD with Mobilenet" model from Tensorflow. And training went fine.
Now when I try to test the performance of inference graph by running object_detection_tutorial.ipynb on an image, I get following  error:

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size X into shape (a,b,c)

X,a,b,c are different values for different test images.

I don't think image size is causing the issue as model must perform independent of input image size. Infact, I get this error even with an image I used for training.

Please help here.

Comment: Issue is solved. My image has 4 channels, while program expects image with 3 channel.

Comment: Could you share how did you solve the issue? I am having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: I programmatically changed the input image to 3 channels. OpenCV has function for that.

Comment: Check if image has fourth channel.If yes, use cv2.cvtColor


if len(img.shape) > 2 and img.shape[2] == 4:
    #convert the image from RGBA2RGB
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @Mandroid, programmatically changing the input image to 3 channel might be the way to go, but this is how I ended up solving my issue.

Note: I am not sure that removing alpha from the images might have some consequences. This is some kind of information loss however.

Replacing `image = Image.open(<image_path>)` with `image = Image.open(<image_path>).convert('RGB')` did the job for me.